# dcolumn italicize header for me

Tags: tables, booktabs, dcolumn

I am trying to use `dcolumn` to align the decimals for me. I am using `booktabs` while constructing the table. The code I have is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l .}
\toprule
M & N \\
\midrule
5 & 12 \\
10 & 24.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Everything seems to be perfectly fine except that the N was *italicized* for me. How can I do this without having to *italicized* my header?

I am so sorry I couldn't post an image because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: I don't know _why_ this is happening, but `\textup{N}` cures it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I just feel cgnieder's answer is most direct

Comment: I used `\textbf` as bold in headings is normal, you could use `\textup` instead but without the `\multicolumn` the heading will be off-center it will be aligned as a number with no `.` rather than centred in the column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't really that it is italicized, it is in *math mode*. As usual to over-ride a tabular template you can use `\multicolumn` so

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{M}}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{N}}\\
```